# Access methods of protected composite object from main object

Tags: python, design-patterns, composition, protected

I wanted to verify the way I'm using methods of composited and protected object, is correct or not.
Here putting sample code where I'm accessing method of class A using object of Class B.

````
class A:
    # initialisation of class A
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    # method a, I want to call this method from other's object
    def method_a(self):
        print("Perform operation a")
        

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        # initialisation of class B
        # Creating composite and protected object
        self._a = A()
        
    # introducing a method to support a method of a protected object(self._a)
    def via_b(self):
        # calling method of class A
        self._a.method_a()
        

# creating object of class B
b = B()

#Way1: # is this valid to call?
b._a.method_a()

# Way2: or I should use this?
b.via_b()```

In way 2 I see the disadvantage that just to use a method of class A, need to introduce a method in class B.
Can I use Way 1 in code?
````

Comment: since you defined `via_b` you might as well use it, it looks cleaner. neither of them is "wrong" though, in python protected and private and such are suggestions, not hard rules because [we are all consenting adults](https://python-guide-chinese.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/latest/writing/style.html#we-are-all-consenting-adults)

Comment: I've defined via_b is to show the problem statement. But in actual code it is not present. Also, I don't want to defined via_b because it is just adding function call and no processing is being done here.

Comment: Or you okay to add this function (via_b) call to make it cleaner from programming practice.

Comment: they are both "correct" but it is recommended to avoid using "private" members so `via_b` would be more correct, read the link about "consenting adults" its short